# Make package available from browser and as npm package

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have `main.js` and two function on this file to export, like:

```
export function one() {}

export function two() {}
```

Next, I imported functions to `index.js`, with `import`:

`import { one, two } from './src/main'`

And bundled it, with `webpack`, and used `index.js` as entry point.

How I can make, to use this script, as npm package, and as CDN from bundled script (or just local connect from path)?

I found, solution like:

```
import { one, two } from './src/main'

window.one = one
window.two = two

export { one, two }
```

But, it's now seems very neat.
Thanks, for your ideas and comments.

Comment: For a library that needs to be compiled into different module flavours I would rather use [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/).

Comment: I made a whole blog post about this : http://dev.topheman.com/package-a-module-for-npm-in-commonjs-es2015-umd-with-babel-and-rollup/ - you can keep the babel and rollup part and skip the rest.